# Security Group Id: sg-12345 not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I was trying to import an existing Security Group in CDK by using SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId method and it failed with the following error:

Security Group Id: sg-12345 not found! (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidGroup.NotFound; Request ID: 8e2cd924-075d-4c64-b5ba-2e1d9c72fe95; Proxy: null)

Below is my CDK code:

`const sg = SecurityGroup.fromSecurityGroupId(this, 'sgFromLookUp', 'sg-084c533df9d662439');`

I double checked that the security group id is correct, I also tried the other 2 methods for security group look up:

`SecurityGroup.fromLookupById() and SecurityGroup.fromLookupByName()`

All of them returned the same error, any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the security group is looked up after the InterfaceVpcEndpoint which is referencing to it, because I didn't add dependency of the security group to the InterfaceVpcEndpoint. I managed to look up the security group before referencing to it and it works now.

Code that works:

```
// Create security group
const sgConstruct = new SgConstruct(this, 'SecurityGroup', { vpc: props.vpc });

// Create endpoints
new VpcEndpointsConstruct(this, 'VpcEndpoints', { sg: sgConstruct.sg, subnets: props.subnets, vpc: props.vpc });
```

Comment: Could you add a code snippet that solved the issue so that the answer would be more helpful for whoever has the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

https://kuchbhilearning.blogspot.com/2022/10/get-security-group-from-id-aws-cdk.html

This can help you get started. CDK does provide methods based on which we can get the security group from id.